# Batch File use to run command immediately, now there is a delay of 10-12 seconds

Tags: batch-file, random, delay

I haven't changed anything in the file, and it worked perfectly for over a month, but now this delay is really starting to annoy me and I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it.

```
@echo off

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "Music_PATH=C:\Music\ESmusic"
set counter=0

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('forfiles /p "%Music_PATH%" /m *mp3') do (
set Rand_PATH[!counter!]=%%~nxa
set /a counter+=1
)

set /a Random_Music=%random% %% %counter%
set "Full_PATH=%Music_PATH%\!Rand_PATH[%Random_Music%]!"

echo Random Music & echo. & echo !Rand_PATH[%Random_Music%]!
start "" "%Full_PATH%"

Timeout 23
taskkill /f /IM winamp.exe


pause >nul
```

Here is the file for reference. Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: There's a dozen lines there. Have you worked out which particular lines cause the delay?

Comment: `start "" winamp.exe "%Full_PATH%"` may alleviate the problem.Is the delay of which you complain appearing between the `echo`es of the random trackname and the track start or somewhere else?

Comment: `FORFILES` is notoriously slow.  I have no idea why you would be capturing the output of `FORFILES` with a `FOR /F` command. You can just use a basic `FOR` command to do what you want. `for %%a in (%Music_PATH%\*mp3) do ......`

Comment: Just to reiterate, this file executed perfectly with no delay for a month, but suddenly it has one.

I tried your suggestion, Magoo, but it didn't change anything. 
When I execute the file, it opens Command Prompt, and just sits there blank for the length of the delay, before executing the command.

Comment: Should also note that the more music files you have the slower this batch file will run for two reasons.  1) You have more files iterate. 2) You are growing the number of variables within your environment because of having more files. Setting a couple hundred or even a couple thousand variables in the environment will slow down a batch file.

Comment: @Squashman Removing the /F and forfiles worked to fix it! Thank you!